# $\det(A \otimes B - B \otimes A) = 0$ why? Why $rk(M) = n^2-n$ ? Why  x and -x in Spec(M) ?  

Tags: matrices, tensors

Let $A$, $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices.

It seems $\det(A \otimes B - B \otimes A) = 0$.

Moreover it seems that the kernel of $A \otimes B - B \otimes A$ contains $n$ vectors.

Here is MatLab code to check:

n=4; a=randn(n,n);b=randn(n,n);svd(kron(a,b)-kron(b,a))

You will see that the are exactly n zeros in svd, so the rank is n^2-n,
for generic matrices.

This should be very simple, but I cannot see why ..

[EDIT]. 
If matrices A,B commute and have joint eigenbasis $v_i$. Then $v_i\otimes v_i$ generate the kernel.

David Speyer provided correct answer which I accept.
The answer given before is wrong. AoB-BoA (xoy+yox)=AxoBy+AyoBx -BxoAy- ByoAx is no zero by no means. Moreover if it would be true the kernel would be n(n-1)/2 dimensional. However it is n-dimensional typically as it  can be seen by experiments.
[END EDIT].

[EDIT 2 ]. 
Additional observation  non-zero eigenvalues of
$M= A \otimes B - B \otimes A$, comes in pairs: x and -x.

How to explain ?

[End EDIT]

---

[EDIT 2]

Here is some numertical example

> > n=2; a=diag(rand(n,1)),  b=rand(n,n), m= kron(a,b)-kron(b,a), [v d]=eig(m), diag(d)

a =

```
0.4494         0
     0    0.6596
```

b =

```
0.7532    0.0292
0.8047    0.7798
```

m =

```
     0    0.0131   -0.0131         0

0.3617   -0.1464         0   -0.0192
```

-0.3617         0    0.1464    0.0192

```
     0   -0.5308    0.5308         0
```

v =

```
0.0232   -0.0232    0.0531   -0.0007
```

-0.3305   -0.0711    0.0000   -0.1309

```
0.0711    0.3305   -0.0000   -0.1309
```

-0.9409    0.9409    0.9986    0.9827

d =

-0.2265         0         0         0

```
     0    0.2265         0         0

     0         0    0.0000         0

     0         0         0    0.0000
```

ans =

-0.2265
    0.2265
    0.0000
    0.0000

[end edit]

Motivation comes from this question on MO, c1=a , c2=b:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97036/relaxing-commutativity-for-c1-c2-find-q1-q2-1-c1-c2q1c2-q2c1-2-q1-q20/

Comment: This question is a bit more subtle than one might expect. Unless I'm mistaken, it is essential that $V$ is finite dimensional. As an infinite dimensional counterexample consider the space of univariate polynomials $V=k[x]$, when $V\otimes V$ can be viewed as bivariate polynomials $k[x,y]$. If $A$ is multiplication by $x$ and $B$ is multiplication by $(x+1)$, then $A\otimes B$ (resp. $B\otimes A$) is multiplication by $x(y+1)$ (resp. $(x+1)y$). Therefore $A\otimes B- B\otimes A$ is multiplication by $$x(y+1)-(x+1)y=x-y,$$ which is an injective mapping (but not surjective)...

Comment: ...(cont.) Therefore a proof of this claim will need to use the assumption that $V$ is f.d.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proof for generic $A$ and $B$. Let $v_1$, ..., $v_n$ be the eigenvectors of $A^{-1} B$, and $\lambda_1$, ..., $\lambda_n$ the eigenvalues. Defining $w_i = B v_i$, we have $A^{-1} w_i = \lambda_i v_i$ or $A v_i = \lambda_i^{-1} w_i$.

So 
$$(A \otimes B - B \otimes A) (v_i \otimes v_i) = (\lambda_i^{-1} w_i \otimes w_i) - (w_i \otimes \lambda_i^{-1} w_i) = 0.$$

It is not clear to me exactly what happens if $A$ is not invertible, or if $A^{-1} B$ is not diagonalizable, or if some of the $\lambda_i$ are zero. However, rank can only go down under specialization, so the kernel of $A \otimes B - B \otimes A$ is always at least $n$ dimensional.

---

Another proof: WLOG $2$ is invertible in the base field. Then, $M$ carries $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ to $\bigwedge^2 V$ (both regarded as subspaces of $V \otimes V$) and vice versa. Since $\dim \mathrm{Sym}^2(V) = \dim \bigwedge^2 V + n$, the map from $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$ to $\bigwedge^2 V$ must have kernel of dimension at least $n$.

---

Regarding the symmetry of the spectrum, let $\sigma$ be the map $V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ which switches the tensor factors. Then $\sigma M = - M \sigma$, so $M$ is conjugate to $-M$. So $\mathrm{Spec}(M) = - \mathrm{Spec}(M)$, as desired.

Comment: Great, thank you ! the only thing Av= 1/lambda w... Do you have guesses about x and -x in Spec(M) ?

Comment: +1 The argument involving the second symmetric and exterior powers is just so...

Answer (score 4):

Edit: There is apperently a mistake. I will deal with this later today/on the weekend.

As a map of vector spaces $A\otimes B-B\otimes A$ is nothing else but the map
$$V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$$
which sends 
$$x\otimes y\mapsto A(x)\otimes B(y)-A(y)\otimes B(x)$$
Clearly this map has non-trivial kernel since $x\otimes y+y\otimes x$ is sent to zero for all $x,y$. Therefore the determinant is zero.

For your second question: This can't be quite right. Take for example $A=B$ and the kernel has dimension $n^2$. A lower bound for the dimension of the kernel is given by $\binom n2$, as this is the dimension of the subspace spanned by the vectors above.

I would assume that you should get this lower bound $\binom n2$ most of the time since you take random matrices which are dense and non-singular with probability 1.

Comment: Double shame on me. First this did not come to my mind, second I did not notice this is wrong.

Comment: hmm?  What is wrong?

Comment: the second displayed equation is wrong, in fact $x\otimes y \mapsto Ax\otimes By - Bx\otimes Ay$